# SQL Server - delete using "where records in" causes blocking while direct record selection does not

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem where a delete is running inside a transaction
Without committing the delete I run another delete in another transaction
If I use "delete where record in (select...)" the delete is blocked by the original transaction
However if I use "delete where record in (actual record)" the delete goes through straight away

```js
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1] ([token] [varchar] (10) not null, [superToken] [varchar] (10) not NULL, [nr] INT NOT NULL)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test1] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([token], [nr]) ON [PRIMARY]
insert into dbo.test1 (token,supertoken,nr) values ('1','1', 123)
insert into dbo.test1 (token,supertoken,nr) values ('2','2', 456)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test2] ([token] [varchar] (10) not null, [supertoken] [varchar] (10) not NULL)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test2] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_test2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([token]) ON [PRIMARY]
insert into dbo.test2 (token, supertoken) values ('1','1')
insert into dbo.test2 (token, supertoken) values ('2','2')

/* Begin Step 1 */
-- run this query in window 1 - do not commit
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DELETE test1 FROM test1 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE token IN (SELECT token FROM test2 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE supertoken='1'))

-- run this query in window 2 - will cause blocking
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DELETE test1 FROM test1 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE token IN (SELECT token FROM test2 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE supertoken = '2')
-- can now rollback all transations
/* End step 1 */


/* Begin Step 2 */
-- run this query in window 1 - do not commit
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DELETE test1 FROM test1 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE token IN ('1') -- what sub query in step 1, query 1 returns

-- run this query in window 2 - will NOT cause blocking
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DELETE test1 FROM test1 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE token IN ('2') -- what sub query in step 1, query 2 returns
-- can now rollback all transations
/* End step 2 */
```

Comment: And the delete that you are not committing (I think is not shown here) involves the Table1 and/or the Table2?

Comment: It can depends on blocking granularity. They will generates different execution plans.

Comment: So what is actually surprising about that? Tran 2 seems to read from records that tran 1 already X-locked. What do you want to happen?

Comment: Can you try adding the (nolock) query hint to the select statement, if that is what's causing the lock?

Comment: And the delete that you are not committing (I think is not shown here) involves the Table1 and/or the Table2? - correct is not shown here, is deleting from Table1

Comment: Adding the (nolock) did not resolve either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get around this by saving the parent.Token from table2 into a variable.  This looks like it'll work since your tokens appear to be uniqueidentifiers, and because of this the subquery will return at most 1 result:

```
DECLARE @ChildToken UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SELECT  @ChildToken = parent.Token
FROM    Table2 parent
WHERE   parent.SuperToken = 'E38D2055-7D52-4C58-A50E-5297B8A58659'

DELETE  child
FROM    table1 child
WHERE   child.Token = @ChildToken
```

Comment: Have put up a proper example of what I have in the app - the table being deleted from has a PK comprised of two columns. Without the second column there is no blocking.